# Trying to implement Toolbar with AppCompat v21

Tags: android, toolbar, android-appcompat

I'm trying to implement the Toolbar using AppCompat v21 following this guide, http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/  however I am unable to launch on KitKat or Lollipop and get the same error message (below).  I fully believe I have the theme set up correctly but I am stuck at this point and have been for over a day.  I've searched unsuccessfully for the solution so now I'm asking for some help.  Thanks!

```
> 11-29 06:08:46.892  29771-29771/com.chaoticearth.chaoticearth E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ce.ce, PID: 29771
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ce.ce/com.ce.ce.DrawerActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:151)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
            at com.ce.ce.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:16)
            at com.ce.ce.DrawerActivity.onCreate(DrawerActivity.java:92)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my /res/values/themes.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="CETheme" parent="AppTheme" ></style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/MidnightBlue</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/LightYellow</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

</style>
```

Here is my /res/values-v21/themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>

    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/ChaosBlue</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/MidnightBlue</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/LightYellow</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/ChaosBlue</item>

</style>
```

Here is a snippet from my DrawerActivity.java where the error is being thrown:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setActionBarIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
```

And a snippet from the BaseActivity.java that is being called out:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getLayoutResource());
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

And finally here is a snippet from my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CETheme"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally stumbled onto the reason, in my AndroidManifest I was setting a theme for my DrawerActivity, this was causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing **android:colorPrimaryDark** with **colorPrimaryDark** and **android:colorAccent** with **colorAccent** in your res/values/themes.xml.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, that was not the reason but still those values needed to be changed.